# Rails - time zone conversion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I'm trying to convert a datetime with an external timezone field into UTC.  Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work?

```
time_str = '2016-03-01 00:00'
zone_str = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'

Time.use_zone(zone_str) { Time.parse(time_str).in_time_zone('UTC') }
```

What I'm expecting:

```
'2016-03-01 08:00'
```

What I'm getting:

```
'2016-03-01 06:00'
```

Basically, it's ignoring my `use_zone` call and just using my local time zone, which is Central.

What should I be doing instead?

-- edit --

Note that I am NOT trying to set the time zone across the entire application.  I am ONLY trying to take a single set of inputs (time and time zone in separate form fields) and convert those to UTC.

Comment: I accepted @Ilya's solution, but I found the problem with my specific code.  `Time.use_zone(zone_str) { Time.zone.parse(time_str).in_time_zone('UTC') }` I was doing `Time.parse` instead of `Time.zone.parse`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
 time = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(zone_str).parse(time_str)
 time.in_time_zone('UTC')
 #=> Tue, 01 Mar 2016 08:00:00 UTC +00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
time_str = '2016-03-01 00:00'
zone_str = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
time = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(zone_str).parse(time_str)
time.in_time_zone('UTC')
```

use this above code.

Comment: I don't want to assign it across the entire app - only for one set of inputs.

Comment: So you changed your incorrect answer by copying the correct answer verbatim?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
time_str = '2016-03-01 00:00'
zone_str = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
Time.zone = zone_str
Time.zone.parse(time_str).in_time_zone("UTC")
```

Comment: That works, but there are dangers to setting `Time.zone` with the intention of using it only for a single request.  Apparently that can leak into the next request in the thread.